# New cords for larger line

Tags: geometry

I have a class representing lines on two-dimensional space:

```
class Line {
   Point start;
   Point end;

   Float length; // calculated property, something like sqrt(pow(end.x - start.x, 2) + pow(end.y - start.y, 2))
}
```

I want a method to make a line bigger from the center.

For example, if I create some parallel to X:

```
Point start = Point(1, 3)
Point end = Point(1, 10)
Line newLine = Line(start, end) // newLine.length here is 7
```

and then call method **makeBigger**:

```
newLine.makeBigger(4); // pass number of points here
```

I want to receive new line (or modify old's start / end properties) with **start = (1,1) / end = (1, 12)**, so its length becomes 11.

Please note, that I want to consider angles as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand,  `makeBigger(4)` denotes than you want to increase length by 4. So use simple proportionality

```
 newlength = length + increasevalue

 dx = (end.x - start.x) / 2
 mx = (end.x + start.x) / 2  
 newstart.x = mx - dx * newlength / length 
 newend.x = mx + dx * newlength / length 
 and similar for y
```